# Prove that if k is a field, then any affine open subset of the affine n-space A_n^k is principal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I think the question is clear and famous too but i didn' find an answer on this site, so :

k : is a field not necessarily ( an algebraic closed field ).

An open subset of the scheme is an open in the topological sens ( we know that A_n^k is a topological space).

A principal open is the non vanishing locus of a given function ( a polynomial function of n variables )

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20782/ring-theoretic-characterization-of-open-affines

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician sorry, i am a begginer in this field and i still don't find a link between my question and what you suggest !!